# Javascript Azure function with beta runtime does not return response body for error HTTP responses

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

With Javascript Azure functions on beta runtime, I have come across an issue where if the function returns success response (200, 201), the response body returned from context.res is correctly returned.

But if the HTTP status is set to 400 or 404, the client gets standard response like "Bad Request" in response body regardless of what response body is set in the function.

I am able to reproduce this even on auto-generated java script function.

Code (standard auto-generated code)

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request 
body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

With v1 runtime, if name is not specified in query or request body, HTTP status is set to 400 and response body correctly contains "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body".

With beta runtime, HTTP status is set to 400 but response body just contains "Bad request"

Does the response body need to be returned in a different way for beta runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, it's a known issue for beta runtime.

Please see [Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.11888 Announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/117).

> HttpTrigger does not return response content properly. For example following code will return "Bad Request" instead of "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body": `return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");`
>
> If this is blocker, you can use previous version by setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.11857-alpha(in Application settings).

**Update**

This issue has already been fixed from [2.0.11933](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11933-alpha).

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful.